# Angular js magic strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularJs what's the optimal approach for getting rid of magic strings,

For example,

```
//app.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

//accountController.js
angular.module('starter.controllers')
    .controller('AccountCtrl',
        function($scope) {

        }
    );

angular.module('starter')
    .config(function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state($area.state, {
            url: '/account',
            views: {
                'tab-account': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
                    controller: 'AccountCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
```

I am thinking of changing so that,

```
//constants.js
var MODULE_STARTER = function(){return 'starter';};
var MODULE_CONTROLLERS = function(){return 'starter.controllers';};
var MODULE_SERVICES = function(){return 'starter.services';};

//app.js    
angular.module(MODULE_STARTER(), ['ionic', MODULE_CONTROLLERS(), MODULE_SERVICES()])
angular.module(MODULE_CONTROLLERS, []);

//accountController.js
var ACCOUNT_CONTROLLER = function() {
    var $area = {};

    $area.url = '/account';
    $area.state = 'tab.account';
    $area.controllerName = "AccountCtrl";

    $area.stateConfig = function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state($area.state, {
            url: $area.url,
            views: {
                'tab-account': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
                    controller: $area.controllerName
                }
            }
        });
    };

    return $area;
};

angular.module(MODULE_STARTER())
    .config(ACCOUNT_CONTROLLER().stateConfig);

angular.module(MODULE_CONTROLLERS())
    .controller(ACCOUNT_CONTROLLER().controllerName,
        function($scope) {

        }
    );
```

So the point is that when I refer the same string value i do not have to repeat the magic strings, also it would be easier to refactor.

Also if i want to refer account controller or it's URL to redirect, i can always get the data from ACCOUNT_CONTROLLER

Does this approach has any disadvantages?

Comment: 1) These aren't really magic strings, per say, but names of code modules...which shouldn't do a lot of changing. 2) If you did want to reference them to allow for, say, a singular edit of a module name, why make it a function? That's extra overhead and typing. Just set the string to a variable and use it.

Comment: Everything changes as per my experience, especially when refactoring, say if the app grows and i need to add another account controller then i might rename it User.AccountCtrl and i might add a new account controller for client with name Client.AccountCtrl. I agree with you on the second one, but is there a better way of doing it than defining global variables

Comment: Honestly, if you're that worried about module names changing, you're probably the OCD type who will constantly change your organization of this new system, leading to as many or more search and replaces to change out var/constant names. I don't mean that to be offensive, I just don't think you're saving yourself any work with this bit of what I see to be over-engineering.

Comment: :) well, no offense taken but I don't think it's OCD to change existing names when a system evolve rather than coming up with confusing names for new ones so that old ones does not have to change, I think we are having an impasse here.